# web2py real time specific table

Tags: html, ajax, web2py

For example in the controller I have the following query:

```
a= db().select(db.my_db.ALL)
```

How can I add in view a button, such that in real time it shows only the rows which have the field a.date bigger than the date that is selected by the user. I have seen that I can use ajax to refresh the table in real time, but I don't know how to add the button with the date.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [web2py's Ajax](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax#The-ajax-function) it's quite easy:

in your model:

```
import datetime
import arrow # nifty library to parse dates, http://arrow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

mem = DAL('sqlite:memory')
mem.define_table('some_data',Field('effdt','date',default=request.now), Field('foo',default='bar'))
for x in range(100):
    when = request.now - datetime.timedelta(x)
    what = arrow.get(when).humanize()
    mem.some_data.insert(foo=what,effdt=when)
```

This will fill a temporary table with some data to view.

In your controller:

```
def index():
    form = FORM(
        INPUT(_type='date', _name='since'),
        BUTTON('click me',_onclick="ajax('{}',['since'],'show_table');".format(URL(f='recent_table')))
    )
    return dict(form=form, prefill=recent_table())
```

Above creates a form with a html5 date input and a button. When the button is pressed the `ajax` function from the web2py library will post the form input `['since']` to the function `recent_table` and drop the results in the DOM elment with id `show_table`.
The return statement offers the form and executes the `recent_table` once so you have data on the first load already.

```
def recent_table():
    if request.vars.since:
        since = arrow.get(request.vars.since).datetime
    else:
        since=request.now-datetime.timedelta(5)
    return mem(mem.some_data.effdt >= since).select()
```

Above reads the `since` parameter posted by the ajax call, or defaults today minus 5 days if no `since` could be found. Then it finds all the rows in the table matching your request.

in your view:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{=form}}

<div id="show_table">
    {{=prefill}}
</div>
```

In the view you include the resulting `form`, define the area where the ajax function should drop it's results (defined `show_table` tin the ajax call) and fill in the `prefill` already calculated so the user has data on the first page load.